# If $f_n \to f$ in $\|\cdot\|$, then $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$. When is the converse true?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Suppose $f_n,f$ are elements in some normed space, and $f_n \to f$ in some norm $\|\cdot\|$, then by the reverse triangular inequality $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$ is automatic. Are there a number of useful results which say when the converse is true; that is, if $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$, then $f_n \to f$ in some norm $\|\cdot\|$?

It is clearly not usually true, for if $z_n$ and $x_n$ are sequences of complex numbers such that $z_n \to e^{i\pi/2}$ and $x_n \to 1$, then they converge in norm on $\mathbb{C}$, but $z_n \not \to x_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

But are such statements (1) true in some of the useful norms, or (2) does there exist any useful results with regards to this question? If the answer is indeed no; I accept answers with insight which can help to understand why it is the case.

Comment: In finite dimensions you can find a converging subsequence (by compactness). In infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces you have $\Vert f_n \Vert \rightarrow \Vert f \Vert$ and $f_n$ converging weakly to $f$ implies that the sequence also converges in norm to $f$. I am not sure what kind of result you are hoping for.

Comment: If the $f_n$ and nonzero, then you can rescale to enforce that $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$, but that puts very little restrictions on the convergence of $f_n$.

Comment: Also if $f$ is not zero, then multiplying by suitable minuses you can mess up the convergence of $(f_n)$, however, $(\Vert f_n\Vert)$ does not feel this "change of phase" (if you are over the complex numbers, then you can also multiply by a more general phase $e^{i x}$ to mess things up).

Comment: The converse is *never* true. Take a constant sequence and its opposite.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Severin Schraven, there is this result for Hilbert spaces:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(f_n)_n$ a sequence in $H$ and $f \in H$. Then $$f_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|} f \quad \iff \quad \|f_n\| \xrightarrow{} \|f\| 
> \,\,\text{ and } \,\, f_n \xrightarrow{w} f$$

Proof:

If $f_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|} f$ then also $f_n \xrightarrow{w} f$ and clearly $\|f_n\| \xrightarrow{} \|f\|$ because the norm is continuous.

Conversely, if $\|f_n\| \to \|f\|$ and $f_n \xrightarrow{w} f$ then

$$\|f - f_n\|^2 = \|f_n\|^2 - 2\operatorname{Re}\langle f, f_n\rangle + \|f\|^2 \to \|f\|^2 - 2\operatorname{Re} \langle f, f\rangle + \|f\|^2 = 0$$
so $f_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|} f$.